# is my way for finite state machine in VHDL wrong?

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

In my VHDL class, we learn to do fsm. However, I found myself doing it differently than my teacher and he doesn't want to accept my way of doing it without explaining why it would be wrong. So I am asking it here.
let's say I have a fsm with this sequence : S1 -> S2 -> S3 -> S1 ... With this, I want the signal `Flag` to be '1' when in the state S2 and '0' otherwise.
My way of doing it is:

```vhdl
process(clk, fsm)
begin
if clk'event and clk = '1' then
   case fsm
       when S1 =>
          fsm <= S2;
       when S2 =>
          fsm <= S3;
       when S3 =>
          fsm <= S1;
   end case;
end if;
end process;

with fsm select
   Flag <= '1' when S2,
           '0' when others;
```

And is way of doing it :

```vhdl
process(clk, fsm)
begin
if clk'event and clk = '1' then
   case fsm
       when S1 =>
          fsm <= S2;
          Flag <= '1';
       when S2 =>
          fsm <= S3;
          Flag <= '0';
       when S3 =>
          fsm <= S1;
   end case;
end if;
end process;
```

Thanks in advance ! And don't hesitate to say it if there is something else you think about my code "ethic"

I Have done some test to see if there might be some kind of error or case where my way of doing it was doing it wrong, but it always work fine..

Comment: In second excerpt, Flag is 1 during S3.

Comment: @Nipo Good point ! haven't thought of this

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher's solution is wrong, because `Flag` is '1' in state `S3`, not in state `S2`.

However, seemingly you asked about the difference of the styles.

We can correct your teacher's solution to:

```vhdl
process(clk, fsm)
begin
if clk'event and clk = '1' then
   case fsm
       when S1 =>
          fsm <= S2;
          Flag <= '1';
       when S2 =>
          fsm <= S3;
          Flag <= '0';
       when S3 =>
          fsm <= S1;
   end case;
end if;
end process;
```

The relevant result at the outputs is equivalent, but this might depend on unknown requirements.

Your style uses one latch less, because you use a combinatorial `Flag`.

If your target's synthesizer optimizes well, both styles most probably produce the same hardware. With less optimization you can observe minor timing differences.

Answer (score 0):

Which style you should use, depends on the requirements you have: if your Design shall be as small as possible, then you would use the combinatorial way (no flipflop for signal flag). If your signal flag must be stable as fast as possible after a clock edge or if flag must have no spikes, then you would use the style from your teacher (resulting in a flipflop).